# Как нормально сверстать такой переход

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал через before, но с ним фон не получается. Плюс надо сделать полоску по краю

Comment: Нижний блок background-image и position absolute

Comment: @RavenTheX, а вы пробовали этот метод? получилось?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием `clip-path`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*=section-] {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[class*=section-]::before,
.section-2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

[class*=section-]::before {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.section-1::before {
  background-image: url(https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/2-nature.jpg);
}

.section-2::before {
  top: -48px;
  min-height: calc(100vh + 48px);
  background-color: #00f;
  background-image: url(https://www.hopestandard.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/21333414_web1_200420-CRM-earth-day-EARTHDAY_1.jpg);
  clip-path: polygon(calc(50% + 1px) 50px, calc(53% + 1px) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.section-2::after {
  top: -50px;
  min-height: calc(100vh + 50px);
  background-color: #00f;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50px, 53% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1"></section>
<section class="section-2"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать через 2 слоя наложенные друг на друга с отрицательным отступом:

- margin-top:-50px и разный z-index,
- position:absolute у одного из слоёв.